# Boolean field being ignored in mongoid query when created by railsadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin

I have a Mongoid model called Announcement:

```
class Announcement
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :message
  field :starts_at, type: DateTime
  field :ends_at, type: DateTime
  field :is_permanent, type: Boolean, default: false
end
```

Most of the things on this model seem to work fine:

```
Announcement.all.count
```

lists all announcements.

When I create an announcement through the console:

```
Announcement.create(is_permanent: true, message: "Hi", starts_at: "2014-09-30", ends_at: "2014-10-30")
```

`Announcement.where(is_permanent: true).to_a` returns it:

```
[#<Announcement _id: 542b5cfa53696d0656010000, created_at: 2014-10-01 01:46:34 UTC, updated_at: 2014-10-01 01:46:34 UTC, message: "Hi", starts_at: nil, ends_at: nil, is_permanent: true>]
```

However, when I create an announcement with a boolean field through the RailsAdmin, it gets put in the database:

```
[#<Announcement _id: 542b4eae53696d0552000000, created_at: 2014-10-01 00:45:34 UTC, updated_at: 2014-10-01 01:12:07 UTC, message: "Cookies!", starts_at: nil, ends_at: nil, is_permanent: "1">]
```

and is_permanent is `"1"`.

As a result, querying for `is_permanent: true` doesn't return that Announcement.

Is this a bug with rails-admin? Did I miss something with my setup? Any help/thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that adding `Mongoid::Boolean` to your model will make Rails Admin insert a mongoid boolean, not just "boolean".

```
field :is_permanent, type: Mongoid::Boolean, default: false
```